# Medical data: is measuring and comparing relative increase okay?

Tags: regression, time-series

**Context:** 30 patients each use a sensor daily, but the sensors unfortunately are not calibrated on the same scale.  Interested in "improvement" over time amoungst groups of patients.

**Question:** To reduce the issue of lacking a common scale, can I look at the relative increase from the first value of each patient over time and use this to assess overall cohort performance?

Answer (score 1):

It would be far better to add a calibration phase to the data collection, e.g., letting the sensor measure an output of known characteristics such as resistance, velocity, etc. - whatever is relevant to measurement process.  Re-measuring this each week would be advantageous.

One of the problems is that the measurements may not be perfectly transformed so that a change score has the right properties.  See the *Bland-Altman Plots* section of *[Biostatistics in Biomedical Research](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat)*.  But a key element of using a change score is that the base period being subtracted is "magical", i.e., is measured under standardized conditions.

You could learn a lot about proper calibration by studying 15 subjects under a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to use standardized mean differences to evaluate the different patients. Using standardized mean differences you can compare different scales, it's the same approach used in meta-analysis

Comment: This makes too many assumptions and may lose some meaning that comes from the dispersion measure you are normalizing by.  If using the standard deviation you are assuming a symmetric distribution.